# Why does calling multiple inserts with vscode's api inserts only the first string?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm playing with vscode's API and I simply tried to insert two strings into the active editor with two edit calls, but only the first string is inserted:

```
    const editor  = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;

    editor?.edit(edit => {
        edit.insert(editor.selection.active, 'test1');

    });

    editor?.edit(edit => {
        edit.insert(editor.selection.active, 'test2');
                
        });
```

Why is that? I know that if I put the two strings in the same call then it works, but I don't get it why it doesn't work with separate calls.

Comment: editor.edit is a promise you have to wait for

Comment: @rioV8 right, thanks, I'm just wondering why the second one fails. It's just an insert at the current position after all, so there is no reason for it to fail, it can be done anytime

Comment: the promise is executed after you exit the current command function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with "Note that the edit-builder is only valid while the callback executes." bit since it never prints `test2` (from https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor).

Perhaps it is because you are creating another edit-builder while the first still exists - it is asynchronous (and may very well be a singleton so another instance may not be created before the first finishes).

This works:

```js
editor?.edit(edit => {
  edit.insert(editor.selection.active, 'test1');
  edit.insert(editor.selection.active, 'test2');
})
```

and this works:

```js
editor?.edit(edit => {
    edit.insert(editor.selection.active, 'test1');
    // edit.insert(editor.selection.active, 'test2');
}).then(success => {
    if (!success) {
      return
    }
    else {
      editor?.edit(edit => {
        edit.insert(editor.selection.active, 'test2');              
  })
}
```